# debugging in Eclipse will defocus when stepping into a new editor

Tags: eclipse

I recently switched from Eclipse Galileo to Eclipse Juno. On Juno I found out a very annoying inconvenience: Whenever I am debugging and I step from one editor into another (when pressing F5 steps into another file), the focus is lost and I have to click on the new editor in order to continue using F5 or F6. In Galileo, I would continue debugging by pressing F5 without having to re-focus the editor. Is that a bug, a change or a feature with options that I could switch off?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you're no alone with this problem in Juno. Take a look at this bug in eclipse maybe it will help you:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372941